# Remove "Category:" word from Woocommerce Archive Pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove just word `Category:` from the header on every [product category page](https://kuzar.locoweekend.com/product-category/torres-elevadoras/), like is shown on image below:

[image]

So that it will only show the category name, and nothing more. I know how to remove entire  block, but haven't found out how to remove just that word. I found the solution below, but it doesn't do anything:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the "`Category:`" prefix by using the [`get_the_archive_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) hook like this:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'so_remove_category_prefix' );
function so_remove_category_prefix( $title ) {
    $title = single_term_title( '', false );
    return $title;
}
```

However, that will remove it for all terms (not just product categories, but blog categories, tags etc).

To specifically target product categories, you can use the [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) function that is provided by WooCommerce:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'so_remove_category_prefix' );
function so_remove_category_prefix( $title ) {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $title = single_term_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
```